# MacOS: two hard drives, one empty

Tags: macos, hard-drive, recovery, diskutil

I was trying to recover my Mac from a backup but something went wrong (the recovery was very slow) so I ended up installing a clear MacOS. However, I did something wrong with diskutil, and now have two disks in the system:

- Untitled - 3 TB
- Apple SSD128E Media - 121 Gb, empty

[image: first volume]
[image: second volume]

I know that I have only one Fusion drive of 3 TB on my Mac.

What is the second drive or volume for? Is it part of my Fusion Drive? Should I and how do I delete it?

I have also noticed that in Recovery Mode where is no local source of MacOS for recovery so I had to do Internet Recovery (and it was MacOS Snow Leopard I believe). Could these two issues be connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Fusion Drive got split. [Apple has some instructions here explaining how to fix it](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207584). I have copied the instructions here, but they made be easier to read and more up to date at the link above.

**The fix will permanently delete all data on these drives, so make sure you have a good backup before you proceed!**

In your case, you may want to get to a newer version of macOS Recovery as Mojave and above have a single, simple command to fix this issue.

To boot to the newest version of macOS recovery that your system can run, do the following:

1. Shut down your computer.
2. Hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to
   boot into the most up-to-date version of macOS Recovery online. This
   will likely be the Mojave or Catalina version of macOS Recovery.

If you booted to Mojave or Catalina recovery, here's what Apple says to do next:

> 2. When you see the macOS Utilities window, choose Utilities > Terminal
>      from the menu bar.
> 3. Type `diskutil resetFusion` in the Terminal window, then press Return.
> 4. Type `Yes` (with a capital Y) when prompted, then press Return.
> 5. When Terminal indicates that the operation was successful, quit
>      Terminal to return to the macOS Utilities window.
> 6. Choose Reinstall macOS, then follow the onscreen instructions to
>      reinstall the Mac operating system. Your Mac restarts from your
>      Fusion Drive when done.

---

Alternatively, if this fails, or if you are on High Sierra recovery or earlier, you can follow the *High Sierra and earlier* set of instructions which are a bit more complex.

> 1. Turn on your Mac, then immediately press and hold Command-R to start up from macOS Recovery. Release the keys you see the Apple logo
>      or spinning globe.
> 2. When you see the macOS Utilities window, choose Utilities > Terminal from the menu bar.
> 3. Type `diskutil list` in the Terminal window, then press Return.
> 4. Terminal displays a table of data about your drives. In the IDENTIFIER column, find the identifier for each of the two internal,
>      physical drives that make up your Fusion Drive. Usually the
>      identifiers are disk0 and disk1. One of them should be 128GB or less
>      in size. The other at least 1TB in size.
> 5. Type the following command, replacing *identifier1* and *identifier2* with the identifiers you found in the previous step. Then press Return.
>
> `diskutil cs create Macintosh\ HD identifier1 identifier2`
>
> **Example**: diskutil cs create Macintosh\ HD disk0 disk1
>
> If you get a disk unmounting error, enter `diskutil unmountDisk identifier`, using the first identifier you gathered previously. Then
>   enter same command again using the second identifer.
>
> 6. Type `diskutil cs list`, then press Return.
> 7. Terminal displays additional data about your drives (volumes). Find the string of numbers that appears after ”Logical Volume Group”
>      for the volume named Macintosh HD. It's a number like
>      8354AFC3-BF97-4589-A407-25453FD2815A.
>
> **Example**:
>   +-- Logical Volume Group 8354AFC3-BF97-4589-A407-25453FD2815A |   ========================================================= |   Name:         Macintosh HD
>
> 8. Type the following command, replacing *logicalvolumegroup* with the
>      number you found in the previous step. Then press Return.
>
>    `diskutil cs createVolume logicalvolumegroup jhfs+ Macintosh\ HD 100%`
>
> **Example**: diskutil cs createVolume 8354AFC3-BF97-4589-A407-25453FD2815A
>   jhfs+ Macintosh\ HD 100%
>
> 9. When Terminal indicates that the operation was successful, quit Terminal to return to the macOS Utilities window.
> 10. Choose Reinstall macOS, then follow the onscreen instructions to reinstall the Mac operating system. Your Mac restarts from your Fusion
>       Drive when done.

Comment: thank you so much! I am now in a middle of clear Catalina installation right from the recovery mode on the only single volume I have. I am also surprised that I can recover my old iMac Late 2012 right to Catalina with no installation and upgrading of older OS step by step.

Comment: the second sequence also works for people who want to make their own fusion drive

Comment: also, if the OP only had 3TB of drive, OP should use replace 100% with 3 TB

Comment: @Westave: Be sure to let us know if this works for you or not!

Comment: I used first option and it did completely work. Just finished installing all my apps. Thank you!

Comment: @Westave: Great! If you could, please accept my answer so other people with the same issue can troubleshoot and solve it.